# Difference between each and map in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, ui-automation, angular-e2e

What exactly is the difference between protractor [map](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) and protractor [each](http://Home%20Quick%20Start%20%20Protractor%20Setup%20%20Protractor%20Tests%20%20Reference%20%20Protractor%20API%205.4.1%20Search%20Enter%20name%20browser%20browser%20angularAppRoot%20waitForAngularEnabled%20getProcessedConfig%20forkNewDriverInstance%20restart%20restartSync%20useAllAngular2AppRoots%20waitForAngular%20findElement%20findElements%20isElementPresent%20addMockModule%20clearMockModules%20removeMockModule%20getRegisteredMockModules%20get%20refresh%20navigate%20setLocation%20getLocationAbsUrl%20debugger%20enterRepl%20explore%20pause%20controlFlowIsEnabled%20ExtendedWebDriver%20Appium_Commands%20webdriver.WebDriver%20actions%20touchActions%20executeScript%20executeAsyncScript%20call%20wait%20sleep%20getPageSource%20close%20getCurrentUrl%20getTitle%20takeScreenshot%20switchTo%20element%20element.all(locator)%20clone%20all%20filter%20get%20first%20last%20$$%20count%20isPresent%20locator%20then%20each%20map%20reduce%20evaluate%20allowAnimations%20element(locator)%20clone%20locator%20getWebElement%20all%20element%20$$%20$%20isPresent%20isElementPresent%20evaluate%20allowAnimations%20equals%20webdriver.WebElement%20getDriver%20getId%20findElement%20click%20sendKeys%20getTagName%20getCssValue%20getAttribute%20getText%20getSize%20getLocation%20isEnabled%20isSelected%20submit%20clear%20isDisplayed%20takeScreenshot%20locators%20by%20addLocator%20binding%20exactBinding%20model%20buttonText%20partialButtonText%20repeater%20exactRepeater%20cssContainingText%20options%20deepCss%20webdriver.By%20className%20css%20id%20linkText%20js%20name%20partialLinkText%20tagName%20xpath%20expectedConditions%20ExpectedConditions%20not%20and%20or%20alertIsPresent%20elementToBeClickable%20textToBePresentInElement%20textToBePresentInElementValue%20titleContains%20titleIs%20urlContains%20urlIs%20presenceOf%20stalenessOf%20visibilityOf%20invisibilityOf%20elementToBeSelected%20element.all(locator).each(eachFunction)%20View%20code%20ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each%20Calls%20the%20input%20function%20on%20each%20ElementFinder%20represented%20by%20the%20ElementArrayFinder.%20%20Example%20View%20%3Cul%20class=%22items%22%3E%20%20%20%3Cli%3EFirst%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%3Cli%3ESecond%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%3Cli%3EThird%3C/li%3E%20%3C/ul%3E%20Code%20element.all(by.css('.items%20li')).each(function(element,%20index)%20%7B%20%20%20//%20Will%20print%200%20First,%201%20Second,%202%20Third.%20%20%20element.getText().then(function%20(text)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20console.log(index,%20text);%20%20%20%7D);%20%7D);%20%20//%20Or%20using%20the%20shortcut%20$$()%20notation%20instead%20of%20element.all(by.css()):%20%20$$('.items%20li').each(function(element,%20index)%20%7B%20%20%20//%20Will%20print%200%20First,%201%20Second,%202%20Third.%20%20%20element.getText().then(function%20(text)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20console.log(index,%20text);%20%20%20%7D);%20%7D);%20Params%20Param%09Type%09Description%20fn%09function(ElementFinder)%09Input%20function%20Returns%20Type%09Description%20!webdriver.promise.Promise%09A%20promise%20that%20will%20resolve%20when%20the%20function%20has%20been%20called%20on%20all%20the%20ElementFinders.%20The%20promise%20will%20resolve%20to%20null.) function? 
The document says each and map both apply the callback function to ElementFinder from the respective ElementFinderArray. But how do they differ from each other? If they are one at the same thing, then why have a duplicate function be it map() or each()?

Comment: map will create / return a new areay and each modifies the old array. At least for Vanilla js

Comment: What does the documentation say? Any links?

Comment: @yunzen  [map](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map)  and [each](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) from documentation

Comment: each loops..... map returns a new data. Not the same thing.

Comment: Why can't I get `map` to return an array of ElementFinders? :(

Answer (score 0):

They both do the same and something different.

They both apply a function to each element of an array and they both return a promise. The promise is different though.

map

> Returns
>   `Type                         Description`
>   `!webdriver.promise.Promise   A promise that resolves to an array of values returned by`
>   `.                            the map function.`

each

> Returns
>   `Type                         Description`
>   `!webdriver.promise.Promise   A promise that will resolve when the function has been`
>   `.                            called on all the ElementFinders. The promise will resolve to null.`

For a description, what a map function does, compare [MDN Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)